# Count the number of a specific object element in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the code that works well with numbers, but they do not work with object types.

```pl
count(_, [], 0).

count(Field, [Field|Tail], N) :-
  count(Field, Tail, N1),
  N is N1 + 1.

count(Field, [H|Tail], N) :-
  Field \= H,
  count(Field, Tail, N).
```

```pl
?- count(1, [1,2,3], X).
X = 1 . % ok

?- count(1, [1,2,3,1], X).
X = 2 . % ok

?- count(elem(temp, _), [elem(temp, val1), elem(temp, val2)], X).
X = 1 . % I expected 2 here.
```

For the last line, I expected `X = 2`, because

- `elem(temp, _) = elem(temp, val1)`
- `elem(temp, _) = elem(temp, val2)`

And, my questions are:

- Q1. Why is it not working?
- Q2. How can I make it work for any types?

Thank you.

Comment: A1. It's not working because `_` is mapped to a single value (`_ = val1` in this case). Once, `val1` is mapped, `val2` is not a match anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working because `elem(temp,_)` is unified with the first item of the list and that unification is propagated throughout the recursive calls. You can observe this by tracing the execution.

```
?- trace, count(elem(temp, _), [elem(temp, val1), elem(temp, val2)], X).
   Call: (11) count(elem(temp, _30894), [elem(temp, val1), elem(temp, val2)], _30926) ? creep
   Call: (12) count(elem(temp, val1), [elem(temp, val2)], _31518) ? creep
   Call: (13) elem(temp, val1)\=elem(temp, val2) ? creep
   Exit: (13) elem(temp, val1)\=elem(temp, val2) ? creep
   Call: (13) count(elem(temp, val1), [], _31650) ? creep
   Exit: (13) count(elem(temp, val1), [], 0) ? creep
   Exit: (12) count(elem(temp, val1), [elem(temp, val2)], 0) ? creep
   Call: (12) _30926 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 1 is 0+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) count(elem(temp, val1), [elem(temp, val1), elem(temp, val2)], 1) ? creep
X = 1 .
```

To make it work you can use predicate [`subsumes_term/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=subsumes_term/2):

```
?- subsumes_term(1, 1).
true.

?- subsumes_term(1, 2).
false.

?- subsumes_term(elem(temp,_), elem(temp,val1)).
true.

?- subsumes_term(elem(temp,_), elem(temp,val2)).
true.

?- subsumes_term(elem(temp,val1), elem(temp,val2)).
false.
```

Thus, a possible solution is:

```
count(_, [], 0).

count(Field, [First|Tail], N) :-
   subsumes_term(Field, First),
   count(Field, Tail, N1),
   N is N1 + 1.

count(Field, [First|Tail], N) :-
  not(subsumes_term(Field, First)),
  count(Field, Tail, N).
```

Running examples:

```
?- count(1, [1,2,3], X).
X = 1 ;
false.

?- count(1, [1,2,3,1], X).
X = 2 ;
false.

?- count(elem(temp, _), [elem(temp, val1), elem(temp, val2)], X).
X = 2 ;
false.
```

A **more efficient** version is:

```
count(Field, List, Count) :-
   count(List, Field, 0, Count).

count([], _, Acc, Acc).

count([First|Tail], Field, Acc, Count) :-
   (   subsumes_term(Field, First)
   ->  Acc1 is Acc + 1
   ;   Acc1 is Acc ),
  count(Tail, Field, Acc1, Count).
```

Comment: thank you! I realized why it wasn't working but couldn't find a way to make it work. This is amazing.